# webpack sass-loader ` An @import loop has been found:`

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to update sass-loader and webpack to latest version but i'm getting an error:  `An @import loop has been found:`

I need to import two files using additionalData property of sass-loader
which is like this:

```
{
     loader: 'sass-loader',
     options: {
               sourceMap: true,
               additionalData: '@import "sass/_themes.scss";@import "sass/_variables.scss"; ',
               sassOptions: {
                   exclude: 'src/store', // the components that are using the `_themes.scss` are located here
                   includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src')],
               },
     },
}
```

and in some of my components i should use `import {Theme} from 'sass/_themes.scss'`
This is where i face the issue of :

```
SassError: An @import loop has been found:
           sass/_themes.scss imports sass/_themes.scss
        on line 1 of sass/_themes.scss
```

**How can i exclude those components from this additionalData import?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `additionalData` also accepts a [function](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#function-1), you can write some conditions in there. For example:

```js
additionalData = (content, loaderContext) => {
  const { resourcePath, rootContext } = loaderContext;

  const relativeFilePath = path.relative(rootContext, resourcePath);
  const isExcluded = relativeFilePath.match(/^src\\store\\.*/);

  return isExcluded
    ? content
    : '@import "sass/_themes.scss";@import "sass/_variables.scss";' + content;
};
```